# rewrite url in web.config redirecting multiple times

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

Here is my code, it is redirecting multiple times

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(over-the-counter-products)\.shtml$" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="over-the-counter-products.aspx"/>
</rule>`
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your matching rules include ***over-the-counter-products***, and your rewritten path also includes ***over-the-counter-products***, so a circular redirection occurs.

I suggest you modify the rewritten URL:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="rewrite-over-the-counter-products.aspx"/>
```

All in all, the matched URL cannot be the same as the rewritten URL, otherwise the rewritten URL will be matched by IIS again.